# How to run Python files with Airflow using Samba connection

Tags: airflow, samba

I have the following problem. I have a data pipeline at work that transforms raw data and loads it to a cloud database, for various projects. There are Python scripts for the project-based transformations, but everything must be done manually (defining the transformer's project-based inputs, run the transformer, load the data).

I want to automate this process with Airflow. I created the above steps as tasks in Python. The Airflow instance is running on some computer, which must reach a network drive, where the raw data and the transformer scripts are located. **The required connection type is Samba**.

I managed to connect to the drive and create a SambaHook object:

```
samba_file_share: Final[object] = SambaHook(connection_id, file_share_name)
```

In one task, I need to call and run the transformer script. With a former solution (without Samba) I used Popen, which worked fine. However, I must use Samba now, and I face the following problem.

I have the path of the transformer script by reading out the root folder of the file share from the Samba object, and join the path of the transformer  to it:

```
samba_file_share._join_path(transformer_path)
```

If I print this out, the path is correct, and the network is available. If I fed it as a string to Popen (or byte string or path-like object) I got the error "No such file or directory".

Can anyone help with it? How can I fed it to Popen to run the script; or should I use something else, not Popen, to run it? The Samba documentation is totally incomplete, I could not found anything there so far.

Thanks,
Marci

This automated Airflow solution works perfectly if I connect from a machine that easily access the network drive.

However, that is only for development, and in production it must run in some other machine which has no direct access to the drive. I must use Samba to connect to it, and it breaks everything.